# Subtraction of pointers in array should be index subtraction or address subtraction?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDaaR.png)
Shouldn't the answer be 2nd ques?

ptr1 saves the address of arr[0] and ptr2 saves the address of arr[3]. So (ptr2-ptr1) should be ((3*4(size of float)) -(0*4)) i.e., subtraction of address not the subtarction of index..

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Arithmetic works as usual; `(a + b) - a == b`.

Comment: pointer - index yields a pointer. pointer - pointer yields the difference between the pointers. The question is very unclear.

Comment: Note in practice, it is recommended to not write code based on pointer arithmetic at all. Current C++ has enough  (zero cost) abstractions to avoid the need to use them.  Also it is best not to write code that assumes a certain memory layout, compilers may add padding bytes to increase performance.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote that

```
float *ptr2 = ptr1 + 3;
```

So according to the usual arithmetic `ptr2 - ptr1` is equal to `3`.:)

The same is valid for the pointer arithmetic.

From the C++20 Standard (7.6.6 Additive operators)

> 5 When two pointer expressions P and Q are subtracted, the type of the
> result is an implementation-defined signed integral type; this type
> shall be the same type that is defined as std::ptrdiff_t in the
>  header (17.2.4).
>
> (5.2) — Otherwise, if P and Q point to, respectively, array elements i
> and j of the same array object x, the expression P - Q has the value i
> − j.

That is after this line of code

```
float *ptr2 = ptr1 + 3;
```

the value of the pointer `ptr1` is equal to `&arr[0]` and the value of the pointer `ptr2` is equal tp `&arr[3]`. The difference yields the number of elements of the array between the first and the fourth elements in the array.

To get the value of the difference of two addresses you can write for example

```
( ptr2 - ptr1 ) * sizeof( float )
```